# Change textview content from an array by Button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a small app which can give randomly added sentences for me and my friend when we hang out together. I was able to do it by use arrays and random function. The problem is the button only works at the first time I push the button, if I push it again nothing change. I am a newbie to Android and Java so I do not understand much. Here is my code:

```
 Random r = new Random(); //Khai báo biến random
    n = r.nextInt(14) + 0 ; //hàm tạo biến random

    //Thêm phần tử vào chuỗi
    mangtrochoi[0]=("do A");
    mangtrochoi[1]=("do B");
    mangtrochoi[2]=("do C");
    mangtrochoi[3]=("do D");
    mangtrochoi[4]=("do E");
    mangtrochoi[5]=("do F");
   /* mangtrochoi[6]=("đéo được đánh sd");
    mangtrochoi[7]=("đánh Thảo 10 cái");
    mangtrochoi[8]=("đánh Nhân 10 cái");
    mangtrochoi[9]=("đánh Nguyên 10 cái");
    mangtrochoi[11]=("đánh Bun 10 cái");
    mangtrochoi[12]=("đánh Tiến 10 cái");
    mangtrochoi[13]=("đánh Giang 10 cái");
    mangtrochoi[14]=("đéo được đánh sd");*/

    //Buoc 3: viet code
    BTNrandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TVhienthi.setText(mangtrochoi[n]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: check the answers below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this code inside you Button `onclickListener`;

```
 BTNrandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random r = new Random(); //Khai báo biến random
            n = r.nextInt(14) + 0 ; //hàm tạo biến random
            TVhienthi.setText(mangtrochoi[n]);
        }
    });
```

So in each press you will generate a random number which will then set the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `n` to a random value inside the click-handler.

```
BTNrandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            n = r.nextInt(14) + 0 ;
            TVhienthi.setText(mangtrochoi[n]);
        }
    });
```